# Populate HighCharts from Array created from SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

I have a SharePoint list with data that I need to display on 9 different charts on a single page. I have created a couple arrays, one to identify the list item to get, and one to identify the chart container.

I have almost everything working properly, with one exception. The code will only display all of the charts if I include an "alert" within the loop. Otherwise only the last chart is displayed. It is the correct information, in the correct container, but the other charts are skipped without the "alert" I have tried both a for and forEach loop. Here is the code:

```
var sc=["Dept1","Dept2"];
var chartName=["Dept1-Chart","Dept2-Chart"];



 function GetChartData() {

sc.forEach(function(unit)
{
alert(unit);
switch(unit) {
 case "Dept1":
    currChart = "Dept1-Chart";
    unit="Dept1";
    break;
 case "Dept2":
    currChart = "Dept2-Chart";
    unit="Dept2";
    break;
} 
currQuery="<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>" + unit + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var splist = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Fiscal');
var splistquery = new SP.CamlQuery();

splistquery.set_viewXml(currQuery);
splistitems = splist.getItems(splistquery);
currentcontext.load(splistitems);
currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,GetChartDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, GetChartDataFail));
}); //close forEach    

}

function GetChartDataSuccess(sender, args) {
var splistitemcount = splistitems.get_count();
if (splistitemcount != 0) {
  var splistitemenumerator = splistitems.getEnumerator();
  while (splistitemenumerator.moveNext()) {

     var currentlistitem = splistitemenumerator.get_current();
     var itemname = currentlistitem.get_item("Title");
     var itemObligated = currentlistitem.get_item("ObligatedFunds");
     var itemRemaining = currentlistitem.get_item("RemainingFunds");
     var itemAllocated = currentlistitem.get_item("AllocatedFunds");
     var seriesitem = {
                       name: itemname,
                      data: [ itemObligated, itemRemaining ]
                  };
     //seriesarray.push(seriesitem);
  }

  DrawChart(itemObligated,itemRemaining,itemAllocated,currChart);
}
}
```

Thank you for any assistance you can give.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your use of global variables to store the values. The success functions are running after your loop completes and so they are accessing the last values. This is why you are only getting the last one drawn unless you pause the loop (ie an alert).

You can fix this by converting your code to something like this:

```
var sc=["Dept1","Dept2"];
var chartName=["Dept1-Chart","Dept2-Chart"];

function GetChartData() {

  var chartResults = {};

  sc.forEach(function(unit) {
    //alert(unit);
    switch(unit) {
      case "Dept1":
        chartResults.currChart = "Dept1-Chart";
        chartResults.unit="Dept1";
        break;
      case "Dept2":
        chartResults.currChart = "Dept2-Chart";
        chartResults.unit="Dept2";
        break;
  }

  var currQuery="<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>" + unit + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
  var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var splist = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Fiscal');
  var splistquery = new SP.CamlQuery();

  splistquery.set_viewXml(currQuery);
  chartResults.splistitems = splist.getItems(splistquery);
  currentcontext.load(chartResults.splistitems);

  currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(chartResults,GetChartDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(chartResults, GetChartDataFail));
}); //close forEach    

}

function GetChartDataSuccess(sender, args) {
  var splistitemcount = this.splistitems.get_count();
  if (splistitemcount != 0) {
    var splistitemenumerator = this.splistitems.getEnumerator();
    while (splistitemenumerator.moveNext()) {

      var currentlistitem = splistitemenumerator.get_current();
      var itemname = currentlistitem.get_item("Title");
      var itemObligated = currentlistitem.get_item("ObligatedFunds");
      var itemRemaining = currentlistitem.get_item("RemainingFunds");
      var itemAllocated = currentlistitem.get_item("AllocatedFunds");
      var seriesitem = {
        name: itemname,
        data: [ itemObligated, itemRemaining ]
      };
      //seriesarray.push(seriesitem);
  }

  DrawChart(itemObligated,itemRemaining,itemAllocated,this.currChart);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the problem persists. The code works great, and displays both charts only if the 'alert(unit);' is uncommented. it can be any alert, but that is the one I am using. The loop is only passing Dept2 information to the "GetChartDataSuccess" function.